# ASP.NET MVC custom controller class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In ASP.NET MVC, how can we make controller classes without using "controller" suffix? I couldn't find a solution on the web. MSDN documentation says that a controller class name must ends with "controller".

Can some expert help me out?

Thank you.

Jerry

Comment: Why would you want to make a controller without the suffix? That's how the framework works.

Comment: Yes you can. But like @jesse i'm curious to know why you want do this?

Comment: While it can be done, it places more of a burden on you if you do so.  Frameworks are designed to improve productivity by following a set plan.  If you want to deviate from that plan significantly, there is little value in using the framework in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a custom controller factory by inheriting the `DefaultControllerFactory` and override the `GetControllerType` method.

```
// instantiate controllers that doesn't have "Controller" suffix.
public class CustomControllerFactory: DefaultControllerFactory
{ 
    protected override Type GetControllerType(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        var controllersNs = "MvcApp.Controllers";
        return Type.GetType(string.Format("{0}.{1}", controllersNs, controllerName));
    }
}
```

And you have to register this controller factory in Global.asax.cs.

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new CustomControllerFactory());
```

**Important**: The `DefaultControllerFactory` does more work to improve the performance by caching the types and other stuff, you have to look into the [source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/944ab06b9c54#src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultControllerFactory.cs) to get a better idea.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I am just curious to see how MVC worked internally. Every time I have to make sure that my controller class has "controller" suffix in it. Based on the link provided by the answer, I know how that works now.